# Why doesnt git diff-tree show the entire path

Tags: git

I am still trying to understand how git works when I ran into this question.

I have a local repo named `training`. And the full path where it is is `/c/training`

After a few commits, when I tried to get the file names and their md5sum value of the files that were part of the commit using the Hash Commit ( SHA value ), using the following command

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r  08dca334d9b6aa416b377566a8d8606f71b5b8da | xargs -I {} md5sum {}
```

The **Output** I got was

```
10b2804a72f5de19bd04b1f500ab840f *folder/file.txt
c3244a3bf0221587a47fc44ebd2c5aa3 *folder/secondnewfile.txt
```

I was expecting the command to show the full path like `/c/training/folder/file.txt`

Is it because `training` was initialised ( as the local repo) and git only tracks from there and is not able to or cannot know the full path to the file ?
Or is something wrong with the way I have written the command?

Comment: When was the last time you saw absolute paths in `git diff`? I'm sure never — `git` doesn't do it.

Comment: @phd never. But I was trying to understand why it doesn't ( the working of how it's done ). I guess Git just doesn't do it.

Comment: "*…why it doesn't…*" Because nobody needs it? People seldom need absolute paths bit often need paths related to the root of the repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git almost never uses absolute paths.  The reason is simple: absolute paths are usually bad.

There are occasions where absolute paths are good, but to turn relative path *R* into absolute path *A* rooted at `$start`, we simply stick `$start` (plus a trailing slash if needed—here I'll just assume it's *in* `$start`) in front of *R*.  If we have all output as *absolute* paths and want *relative* ones, we can strip `$start` from each line, but any line that *doesn't* start with `$start` is now literally impossible to deal with: it's not relative to the `$start` we chose.

This means the interconversion direction is trivial for *R ⇒ A* but hard for *A ⇒ R*.  As such, if it's *possible* to define a system in terms of relative paths *R*, we should do so.  It is in Git, and Git does so.

This also allows us to pick up a Git repository and move it elsewhere.  If Git repositories stored absolute paths, we would not be able to do that.  Relative paths good, absolute paths bad: it's a useful mantra.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>Although vaguely disturbingly close to "four legs good, two legs bad".